# Jerky/choppy DVD stepper motor movement

Tags: stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I, like many others, am playing with a DVD drive stepper motor. I ordered some L298N driver boards, hooked everything up and got movement, but it's choppy. I've tried every orientation of the motor wires. I have identified my coil pairs, but I don't know which is considered A+ and A- or B+ and B-. I've got the arduino set up to run the stepper at 120 rpm and I've determined that the motor itself is a 20 step-per-revolution one. I can tell it to move clockwise and it does, as well as counter-clockwise, but as I said it's quite jerky, and both the heatsink on the L298N chip, as well as the motor itself, get quite hot.

I'm not sure what other information would be useful, I can post a schematic or drawing of my wiring. The code I'm using is just the stepper_oneRevolution example in the arduino IDE. Is the choppiness due to driving it by full steps, or at low speed? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What voltage and speed is jerky? Excessive current means abrupt steps. Lack of smooth acceleration may skip steps

Comment: Sounds like it's doing what a stepper motor does.

Comment: I switched over to using a stepstick driver, still had jerky movement, but after tweaking the potentiometer for the current I managed to reduce, but not eliminate, the jerkiness. Then I toasted the CH340 in my arduino nano somehow, so I got distracted trying to fix that. Later on I'll try a different stepper, with a higher resolution.